# Adblock extension blocks magento items

Tags: magento, browser-extension, adblock

I have just realised that Adblock extension blocks all my product items from [this Magento site](http://cavalet.bg). What should I do to prevent this issue?

Comment: Not a PHP/Magento programming question. Magento Help-Desk questions should be asked over on Magento.Stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two separate ways of dealing with this.

1. Look through your URL keys and the Magento generated URLs and compare them with the match strings used by AdBlock. Eliminate all combinations that AdBlock matches and blocks.
2. Have a banner image that will be detected and blocked by AdBlock and arrange for it to have a non-blocked message behind asking the customer to turn off AdBlock on your site so they can view certain product.

Or just deal with it. People running AdBlock should understand the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

disable the extension and see if your issue get resolved, if that works than remove that extension if its not important

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I want to make my site visible also for users with Adblock extension installed.